# Eclipse Plugin Development : Open popup on an action

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have created a right click menu item. On its click I want to show a small popup filled with certain values. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look under SWT snippets for instructions on opening new windows of various kinds.

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/

Look under the Shell section.